Using Testcontainers in GitLab CI
I am currently working on several microservices, which are run and connected via a docker compose.
The microservice I'm currently working on is the first to receive proper integration testing.
For this I use Testcontainers so that I don't have to rely on a Postgres database running on my computer.
Locally on my computer the tests definitely work and I was able to successfully build and run the service.
I use GitLab as my VCS because I can automate my build jar and build docker image processes there.
However, when I push my latest version, the build process always fails due to the test container.
How should I describe the CI so that this works?
This is my current .gitlab.ci.yml file.
image: openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

stages:
  - build-job
  - build-image

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

build:
  stage: build-job
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*jar

build image:
  stage: build-image
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo "Tagging Docker Image"
    - if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "main" ]]; then
        TAG="latest";
      else
        TAG="dev";
      fi
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:${TAG} .
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE with tag ${TAG}
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:${TAG}
  only:
    - main
    - dev

As I searched on google I found a post with a solution so I tried to add this into my ci.
  services:
    - docker:dind

To add the docker in docker service help me getting a little bit further.
No I got confronted with the following error message:
ProductIntegrationTest > ModifyProductTest() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:795
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:648
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177
                    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException at DataSourceProperties.java:232

I suspect the problem occurs because no information about the connection could be found, although I had actually specified it in my test class as follows:
@Container
public PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>()
 .withDatabaseName("testdb")
 .withUsername("user")
 .withPassword("password");

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
 String dynamicPort = postgres.getMappedPort(5432).toString();
 String dynamicJdbcUrl = postgres.getJdbcUrl();

 System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", dynamicJdbcUrl);
 System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", postgres.getUsername());
 System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", postgres.getPassword());
}

Am I missing something? I unfortunately can't figure out my problem.
